# Pulp constraint with absolute value >= minimum ignored

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to constrain my problem by making the absolute difference of two LpVariables more than 0. Is there anything obvious i am missing in my implementation?

This is an implementation i found on http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/absolute.htm
which ive implemented it in the code below.
I tried changing the value for M but it does not make a difference.

When i enter the actual result into the formula (such that q1x-q2x = 0) i find that this does not fulfill the constraints. However pulp says the solution is optimal.

```
prob = LpProblem("myProblem", LpMinimize)

q1x = LpVariable("q1x",1,8)

q2x = LpVariable("q2x",1,8) 

B12 = LpVariable("B12",0,1)

M=8

prob += (q1x-q2x) + M * B12 >= 1

prob += -(q1x-q2x) + M * (1-B12) >= 1

prob += q1x+q1y
```

*Expected*:

```
 q1x = 1; q2x = 2 or "infeasible"
```

*Actual:*

```
q1x = 1; q2x = 1 "optimal"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not sure I fully understand what your model is meant to be doing - but it looks like you are expecting `B12` to be a binary variable, but you don't seem to declare it as one. Also what is your objective? The objective is nomrmally added to the problen object first (before any constraints).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to allocate two values, q1x and q2x such that their sum is as small as possible, while q1x!=q2x, which i do by making sure their absolute difference is bigger than 0.What difference would it make for B12 to be declared a binary variable?

Comment: From what you have said & your "Expected" result it is clear that you are expecting `q1x` and `q2x` to be integers. However you have not assigned them to be integers, so that can take on any values - for example 1.0000001. Also, on  `B12` looking at your formulation this is a variable which decides which is larger `q1x` or `q2x`. Consider the case where `q1x>q2x`, in this case for the second constraint to work `B12` needs to be 0. Similarly if  `q1x<q2x` then `B12` would need to be 1 for the first constraint to work - but to be used in this way `B12` needs to be binary (allowed to be 1 or 0).

Comment: That fixes it, thanks a lot! :) Aparently it also suffices if B12 is an integer

Comment: An integer which is limited between 0 and 1 is identical to a binary variable so that makes sense.  Please consider posting your working code as an answer and marking it as accepted - so other people can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The very first "constraint" that is added to the `LpProblem` class will always be considered the objective function, as described in [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html) test problem.

Also i am assuming you want your decision variables `q1x` and `q2x` to be integer which you have to be explicit about when defining your variables

Try this:

```
prob = LpProblem('myProblem', LpMinimize)

q1x = LpVariable("q1x",lowBound = 1, upBound = 8, cat = "Integer")

q2x = LpVariable("q2x",lowBound = 1, upBound = 8, cat = "Integer")

B12 = LpVariable("B12", lowBound = 0, upBound = 1, cat = "Integer")

# B12 can be also be defined by: 
#B12 = LpVariable("B12", cat = "Binary")

M = 8

prob += q1x + q2x 

prob += (q1x-q2x) + M * B12 >= 1

prob += -(q1x-q2x) + M * (1-B12) >= 1



prob.solve()

for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, " = ",  v.varValue)
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
```